# How to show a hyperlink inside the description field of an AboutBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I want to place a link inside the description field of my applications about box which will direct users to a wiki page for more help. I can't figure out how to make the address appear as a link.

I set the description through the assembly information properties.

[image]

Comment: The AboutBox is not WPF's, it uses Windows Forms. You can use it inside a WPF application, but just like any other Windows Forms code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a WinForms control you can use to achieve what you want: the `LinkLabel`.

Simply add one to your AboutBox layout and double click it. A handler to its LinkClicked event will be created, and there you can then use `Process.Start` to open your website's URL.

[image: Example of LinkLabel in an AboutBox]

```
public AboutBox1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Text = String.Format("About {0}", AssemblyTitle);
    this.labelProductName.Text = AssemblyProduct;
    this.labelVersion.Text = String.Format("Version {0}", AssemblyVersion);
    this.labelCopyright.Text = AssemblyCopyright;
    this.labelCompanyName.Text = AssemblyCompany;
    this.textBoxDescription.Text = AssemblyDescription;
    this.Link.Text = "Visit our website!";
    this.Link.Tag = WpfApplication2.Properties.Resources.website;
}

private void Link_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start((sender as LinkLabel).Tag.ToString());
}
```

In my case, I've saved the URL as an application resource. And I've showed it separately from the Assembly Description.

If you want the link to appear inside the Assembly Description, it's quite a bit more complicated...

Comment: Thanks, I did this but I had to add to LinkClicked: [`this.linkWebsite.LinkClicked += linkWebsite_LinkClicked;`](https://github.com/HubKing/LinkBrightness/blob/e8168f1e995622a3aa67797f6a97ca316c6ff7ed/LinkBrightness/AboutBox1.cs#L23).

Comment: Right @Jay, thanks for the clarification! I the answer I mention double-clicking the LinkLabel so the LinkClicked method is created automatically, but yeah, with the event subscription it's more obvious